# PHP 5.2.9 build fails on zend_execute.lo - out of memory?

Tags: php, build, compilation, php-internals

I'm trying to get PHP compiled with EXIF support.  Every time I try to build PHP 5.2.9 on my virtual dedicated server running CentOS 5.3, it fails when it gets to building zend_execute.lo.  I tried compiling just that file by itself, and it fails.  Says out of memory allocating [####] bytes after... something.

How can I get PHP compiled?

Comment: Can you update your question with more details and if possible the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zend_vm_execute.c file includes the whole executor and compiling it can easily consume  more than 100 MB of memory. The suggested oslution is to compile on a box with more memory. If that - for whatever reason - is not possible you might try to disable compiler optimizations (take the command which is printed on your screen and replace -=2 with -O0 and run it manually) which will hurt your performance or you can try using another VM implementation using one of these options:

```
--with-zend-vm=CALL
--with-zend-vm=SWITCH
--with-zend-vm=GOTO
```

But that agian might hurt oyur performance and give other trouble. As said: Get a box with more meory and compile there to be safe - you don'T have to compile on the system you're running PHP on as long as the libraries used are using the same version.

Comment: Hmm... I tried compiling ffmpeg just now, and also got an out of memory error. Something tells me I might actually me out of memory... I haven't heard back from support yet, but I'm pretty sure my VPS must just have a shamefully small amount of RAM | It turns out I did just need more memory.  I didn't try these methods in particular, but they are good tips for those who aren't able to just increase their memory :)  Thanks!